# Missing Children

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Using Mongoose with MongoDB, my Schema is as follows:

```
var PartSchema = new Schema({
    partcode: String,
    children: [String]
});
```

And the data looks like the following:

```
[{"partcode":"A1","children":["B1","B2","B3","B4"]},
 {"partcode":"B1","children":["C11","C21","C31","C41"]},
 {"partcode":"B3","children":["C13","C23","C33","C43"]},
```

I can query for A1's children field by using the following static call:

```
PartSchema.static('getChildren', function (partcode, callback) {
    var self = this;
    self.findOne({ partcode: partcode }, childrenOnly)
        .exec(function (err, doc) {
        return self.find({"partcode": {"$in": doc.children} }, exclId, callback);
    });
});
```

This returns (via express)

```
 [{"partcode":"B1","children":["C11","C21","C31","C41"]},
 {"partcode":"B3","children":["C13","C23","C33","C43"]}]
```

What I need is to return all children not found, for example:

```
[{"children":["B2","B4"}]
```

Comment: A post with the title "Missing children"..... xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [**`_.difference()`**](https://lodash.com/docs#difference) method from the lodash library to calculate the array set difference:

```
var _ = require("lodash");
PartSchema.static('getChildren', function (partcode, callback) {
    var self = this;
    self.findOne({ partcode: partcode }, childrenOnly)
        .exec(function (err, doc) {
        var promise = self.find({"partcode": {"$in": doc.children} }, exclId).lean().exec();
        promise.then(function (res){
             var codes = res.map(function (m) {
                 return m.children;
             }),
                 obj = {"children": _.difference(doc.children, codes)},
                 result = [];
             result.push(obj);
             return result;
        });
    });
});
```

-- **UPDATE** --

With MongoDB's **[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)**, you can achieve the desired result. Let's demonstrate this in mongoshell first.

Suppose you insert the following test documents in the parts collection:

```
db.part.insert([
    {"partcode":"A1","children":["B1","B2","B3","B4"]},
    {"partcode":"B1","children":["C11","C21","C31","C41"]},
    {"partcode":"B3","children":["C13","C23","C33","C43"]}
])
```

The aggregation can be useful here given that you have an array of the children partcodes for a given partcode, say `"A1"`, which is `["B1","B2","B3","B4"]`. In this instance, your aggregation pipeline would consist of the following aggregation pipeline stages:

1. [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) - You need this to filter those documents whose children partcodes are not in the `["B1","B2","B3","B4"]` array. This is achieved using the [**`$nin`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin) operator.
2. [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) - This groups all the documents from the previous stream and creates an additional array field that has the parent partcodes. Made possible by using the [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/#grp._S_addToSet) accumulator operator.
3. [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) - Reshapes each document in the stream by adding a new field `partcode` (which will eventually become part of the result object) and suppresses the `_id` field. This is where you can get the array difference between the parent partcode in the criteria and those not in the pipeline documents, made possible using the [**`$setDifference`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference) set operator.

Your final aggregation operator would look like this (using mongoshell):

```
var children = ["B1","B2","B3","B4"];
db.part.aggregate([        
    {
        "$match": {
            "children": { "$nin": children }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "parents": {
                "$addToSet": "$partcode"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "partcode": {
                "$setDifference": [ children, "$parents" ]
            }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

**Output**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "partcode" : ["B2","B4"]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Using the same concept in your Mongoose schema method:

```
PartSchema.static('getChildren', function (partcode, callback) {
    var self = this;
    self.findOne({ partcode: partcode }, childrenOnly)
        .exec(function (err, doc) {
            var pipeline = [        
                {
                    "$match": {
                        "children": { "$nin": doc.children }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$group": {
                        "_id": null,
                        "parents": {
                            "$addToSet": "$partcode"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$project": {
                        "_id": 0,
                        "partcode": {
                            "$setDifference": [ doc.children, "$parents" ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            self.aggregate(pipeline).exec(callback);                
    });
});
```

Or using Mongoose **[aggregation pipeline builder](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate)** for a fluent call:

```
PartSchema.static('getMissedChildren', function (partcode, callback) {
    var self = this;
    self.findOne({ partcode: partcode }, childrenOnly)
        .exec(function (err, doc) {
            var promise = self.aggregate()
                .match({"children": { "$nin": doc.children }})
                .group({"_id": null,"parents": {"$addToSet": "$partcode"}})
                .project({"_id": 0,"partcode": {"$setDifference": [ doc.children, "$parents" ]}})
                .exec(callback);
            });
    });
```

Comment: Hi Chridam - it's almost right. A `console.log` of `result` shows` [{"children":["B2","B4"}]` but the original call shows a mongoose object (with the data no doubt embedded in it).

Comment: I think express expects the `MongooseDocument` format so the opposite is required, in that the `result` is JSON and should be MongooseDocument.

Comment: In addition to the requirement to use mongooseDocument format, a small change was also required. `return m.partcode`, not `return m.children`.

Comment: The aggregation pipeline builder is a really elegant solution. Unfortunately it's still emitting JSON instead of a Mongodoc.

Comment: @Terry Nice one! Updated with the working solution, cheers :-)